# How to change the line order in the forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I want to move the reference "line" Pl to the top of the plot so the order is "PL", "C", "Pr", "T"

```r
event <- c(664,  677,  295 , 407, 2255, 2435,  717,  831,  130,  130,  864,  849,  231,  178, 1222,  632,   76,   51,
           177,  202, 1825, 1943,  723, 815,  188,  186, 175,  154,  124,  116,  542,  578,  
           103,   86,  942,  918,  149,  160,  276,  269,  404,  427,  789,  892)
n <- c(7802,  7801,  1752,  1739, 22961, 22891,  6259,  6303,   713,   730,  6930,  6955,  2012,  2006, 14095,
       7067,   401,   400,   819, 812,  9333,  9291,  3820,  3825,   621,   616,   707,   706,   641,   628,  2725,  
       2704, 502,   501,  9619,  9601,  1913,  1886, 1043,  1040,  3620,  3623,  6813,  6795)

studlab <- rep(LETTERS[1:22], each=2)
treatment <- c("C",  "Pl", "C",  "Pl", "C",  "Pl", "C",  "Pl", "Pr", "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "Pr", "T",  "Pl", "T",  
               "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  "T",  "C",  
               "T",  "C",  "T",  "Pl", "T",  "C", "Pr", "C",  "Pr", "C",  "Pr", "C")

temp <- data.frame(studlab = studlab, event = event, n = n, treatment = treatment)

library(gemtc)
library(netmeta)

temp <- pairwise(treatment, event = event, n = n, studlab = studlab, data = temp, sm ="OR" )

network_bin_re <- netmeta(TE, seTE, treat1, treat2, studlab, data=temp, sm="OR", reference="Pl",
                            comb.fixed=FALSE, comb.random=TRUE)

forest(network_bin_re, ref = "Pl", digits=3, xlab = "Odds Raio")
```

Comment: You could ask the author, but the package seems pretty outdated (2016-12-23). Maybe do forest plots with the [`meta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/meta/index.html) package instead.